# Add conditional formatting to column via API in Smartsheet

Tags: smartsheet-api

Is there a Smartsheet API to add a Conditional Formatting rule, such as "Highlight Column_name when Column_name is blank"?

I see the API documentation has a "conditionalFormat" field for Row and Cell. But I'm not clear on how to create a rule that applies to the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the Smartsheet API does not support managing the conditional formatting rules for a sheet. I'd encourage you to [submit a product enhancement request](https://app.smartsheet.com/b/form/739aa75f30ca43a8a22eb53e4da7d409) for this feature, as numerous other folks have done previously. (Choose **Developers and API** as the response to the first question **What is your feedback about?**) If enough people express interest in this feature, the Smartsheet team may prioritize it on their API roadmap.